# Is Number of Closed votes limited per user?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

While voting a question for close as it was a possible duplicate, i just noticed that my closed votes left are 32. Is the number of votes or closed votes limited?

What will happen after 32 remaining will be used?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the number of close votes is limited. You get 50 close votes per day (24 on other sites in the network). See the Privileges page for a full description: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Comment: Oh, I always thought you to had to buy them from Shog9....so hard to get....

Answer (score 2):

As explained for example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes):

> - Close/reopen votes
>
>   - **Fifty close/reopen votes per day per user on Stack Overflow**
>   - Twenty-four close/reopen votes per day per user on all other sites
>       ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87291/131713))
>   - Close and reopen votes can be cast by users with 3,000 or more
>       reputation
>   - When you have five or fewer votes remaining for the day, a popup
>       will inform you how many votes you have remaining after each vote you
>       cast
>   - **If you reach the limit and try to vote again, a popup will indicate
>       the number of hours you need to wait before voting again**